# Flask and sqlalchemy: handling sessions

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I recently started using Flask + Sqlalchemy for my project, and have been noticing 500 errors after a day of leaving the server up. I think this is due to the database session timing out, but I'm not sure. Are we supposed to make a new session for every request, or is it one for one the Flask app starts?
I have this at the top of my app.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine, func, cast, Float 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship,scoped_session,sessionmaker,aliased
engine = createengine(DB_PATH) 
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine) 
session = Session() 
app = Flask(name_)
```

And then for all queries in the views, I do something like: "session.query(Table)..."
Is this wrong, should I be making a session for every endpoint call?

Answer (score 19):

There are cases when using the [Flask-SQLAlchemy Extension](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) may not be appropriate. For example, if you are managing your model classes and database connection details in a completely different Python module for reuse with software outside of Flask, you don't want/need the extension to manage these things for you.

Assuming you have your own code to connect to the database and create the `Session` class via something like (also assuming `engine` is provided):

```py
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

For pages that require a database connection, you would create an session instance using that object:

```py
# import the "Session" object created above from wherever you put it

def my_page():
    session = Session() # creates a new, thread-local session
    ...
```

When the response is finished we need to remove the session that was created. That needs to be done after the end of the `my_page` function (so we can't close it there), but before the end of the response. To remove it at the right time, add this code when you create the Flask application:

```py
# import the "Session" object created above from wherever you put it

# despite the name, this is called when the app is
# torn down _and_ when the request context is closed

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    ''' Enable Flask to automatically remove database sessions at the
    end of the request or when the application shuts down.
    Ref: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/
    '''
    Session.remove()
```

Note that in the latter instance `remove()` is being called on `Session` (capital S), not `session` (lower s, the thread local instance). SQLAlchemy is aware of which `session` is in which thread and will close the session that was created for the current thread.

There are probably other ways to do this, but this is the idea. Note that SQLAlchemy provides connection pooling for you.

Comment: Could anyone please clarify one thing? The  manual at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/ under "Declarative" section proposes to directly use the object returned from scoped_session without creating a session instance every time and also does not require to use g object. Which way is correct?

Comment: I don't believe you need to use the g object. The scoped_session will return a current session for you, only creating a new one if necessary. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications

Comment: I remove the use of the global "g" object in the example as it was unnecessary since SQLAlchemy internally maintains a global registry of session objects itself.

Comment: Just to clarify what @SmallJoeMan answered to @AlexVB. The object returned from `scoped_session` can be used interchangeably with `()` and without `()`. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer has a couple things wrong with it, though admittedly it *should* work.

1. It relies implicitly on `threading.local()`. While for most applications are fine, it ignores the possibility of `greenlet` being installed, in which case the local thread ID is not enough.
2. It unnecessarily uses `g`. As noted in a comment, the `scoped_session` already handles this part.

Flask itself does not manage threads, that is the responsibility of the WSGI server. Appropriately, [per the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications), relying on thread scope is not the recommended way to store the db session, though it should work fine because the request is likely directly associated with the thread.

> In particular, while using a thread local can be convenient, it is preferable that the `Session` be associated *directly with the request*, rather than with the current thread.
> Thus, it is preferable to use a custom scope instead according to the documentation so we may associate our session directly with the request context. This can be accomplished using a [custom created scope](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes).

*pseudocode from the SQLAlchemy docs*

```py
from my_web_framework import get_current_request, on_request_end
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=some_engine), scopefunc=get_current_request)

@on_request_end
def remove_session(req):
    Session.remove()
```

For SQLAlchemy, the cleanest object to attach the session to appears to be the *Application Context*, as this is the highest level variable directly associated with a request. Here is [the flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/#how-the-context-works) on how the Flask context works.  You may access the internal [LocalStack](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/local/#werkzeug.local.LocalStack) with the *AppContext* instances via the [`_app_ctx_stack`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask._app_ctx_stack). [This stackoverlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845889) points to the same solution. The `_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__` function is helpful because it either returns the thread id or calls a greenlet function to give a usable identifier if that is installed. That said, flask [does appear to use the thread local itself](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/design/#thread-locals) for many things. I searched and searched but could not find anything that guaranteed a WSGI server such as gunicorn or uwsgi would create a thread for each request. If anyone has a source on that, I'd love to see it. Regardless, the recommended approach is to use the application context, and this is semantically cleaner than relying on a thread having the same lifetime as a request.

Finally, *another comment mentions using Flask-SQLAlchemy*. While this is a good idea for most projects, I don't think it always makes sense. Personally, I wanted my model definition to be defined with SQLAlchemy, not through Flask-SQLAlchemy. I  think it is likely (in my case) that the models will be used outside of Flask in the near future. I also wanted didn't want a different API than SQLAlchemy. period. While I suppose they're likely extremely similar if not entirely the same, it's not using SQLAlchemy itself which I didn't like. I retroactively found a [blog from towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/use-flask-and-sqlalchemy-not-flask-sqlalchemy-5a64fafe22a4) that went to the same conclusion.

All this said, my solution looks pretty much the same to what the towardsdatascience folks did. I'm adding in relevant portions [from a repo they published](https://github.com/edkrueger/sars-flask/tree/master/app) that does this.

**main.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, _app_ctx_stack
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.session = scoped_session(SessionLocal, scopefunc=_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__)

@app.teardown_appcontext
def remove_session(*args, **kwargs):
    app.session.remove()
```

**database.py**

```py
  
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test.db"
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

The subject get's pretty complex, so I welcome comments and I'll update the answer, though hopefully this research helps others.

Comment: Hi Nic, I posted a question regarding session management across requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65927436/how-to-keep-a-session-open-across-separate-requests-with-flask-sqlalchemy).
Would your solution work for this problem?

Comment: No, in this example I tie the db session to the application context, which is unique per request, and I tear it down after.
It smells bad to me to try and do this between REQUEST - a shared session. You could do this of course using the method I've defined, probably ideally with Redis, though.. I would really consider if that is actually required with your design requirement. I'd be hard pressed to find a situation where it is necessary.

Comment: `_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__` doesn't appear to be available in Flask 2.2.1.

Comment: @ggorlen you can use scopefunc=greenlet.getcurrent instead. see https://github.com/osohq/oso/pull/1559/files

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the great [Flask SQLAlchemy Extension](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) which handles session management and connection pooling. Additionally it handles opening and closing of sessions based on requests, etc.

You can check out the relevant SQLAlchemy documentation for more detail: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#session-frequently-asked-questions.

From the docs:

> Some web frameworks include infrastructure to assist in the task of aligning the lifespan of a Session with that of a web request. This includes products such as Flask-SQLAlchemy, for usage in conjunction with the Flask web framework, and Zope-SQLAlchemy, typically used with the Pyramid framework. SQLAlchemy recommends that these products be used as available.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully read [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664436/flask-and-sqlalchemy-handling-sessions#answer-65925792) and SQLAlchemy's class definition in `lib/python3.8/site-pakages/fkask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py`,

I did,

```
from flask import request, current_app
from flask import _app_ctx_stack
from app import db

SessionLocal = db.create_scoped_session(options={'autocommit': False,
                                                      'autoflush': False,
                                                      'bind': db.engine,
                                                      'scopefunc':_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__
                                                      })

with SessionLocal() as session:
    try:
        session.begin()        
        session.add(some_data_from_request)
        session.commit()
    except Exception as ex:
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()
```

where "db" object is created as below. (same as the second example of initiation in the comment of SQLAlchey's class definition.)

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Comment: You don't really need to do this - Flask-SQLAlchemy [already uses the app context by default](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/818c947b665206fe8edd8c1680b18ce83d3e4744/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L776).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for your comment! So, which means, I don't have to create a new session object for the transaction management? Just doing `session = Session()` is sufficient for my case?

Comment: If you're using flask-sqlalchemy, just use `db.session` or `MyModel.query` as appropriate.  Flask-SQLAlchemy abstracts away some of the session management that you would do with vanilla SQLAlchemy.  If you aren't doing anything exotic, follow the examples in the [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks again! When I did `db.session.begin()` I got "A transaction is already begun on this Session" error. If I removed `db.session.begin()`, data was stored in DB correctly (db.session.commit() and db.sessoin.rollback() worked as I expected). However, since I felt very uncomfortable with it and wanted to clearly describe the savepoint in my code, I did `with db.session.begin_nested():` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042856/sqlalchemy-session-begin-nested-with-session-commit).