# Flask SQLAlchemy sessions out of sync

Tags: python, multithreading, session, sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I have a Flask REST API, running with a gunicorn/nginx stack.  There is global SQLAlchemy session set up once for each thread that the API runs on.  I set up an endpoint /test/ for running the unit tests for the API.  One test makes a POST request to add something to the database, then has a finally: clause to clean up:

```
def test_something():
    try:
        url = "http://myposturl"
        data = {"content" : "test post"}
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        result = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers).json()
        validate(result, myschema)
    finally:
        db.sqlsession.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.content == "test post").delete()
        db.sqlsession.commit()
```

The problem is that the thread to which the POST request is made now has a "test post" object in its session, but the database has no such object because the thread on which the tests ran deleted that thing from the database.  So when I make a GET request to the server, about 1 in 4 times (I have 4 gunicorn workers), I get the "test post" object, and 3 in 4 times I do not.  This is because the threads each have their own session object, and they are getting out of sync, but I don't really know what to do about it....

Here is my setup for my SQLAlchemy session:

```
def connectSQLAlchemy():
    import sqlalchemy
    import sqlalchemy.orm
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string(DBConfig.USER, DBConfig.PASSWORD, DBConfig.HOST, DBConfig.DB))
    session_factory = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(session_factory)
    return Session()

# Create a global session for everyone
sqlsession = connectSQLAlchemy()
```

Answer (score 7):

Please use flask-sqlalchemy if you're using flask, it takes care of the lifecycle of the session for you.

If you insist on doing it yourself, the correct pattern is to create a session for each request instead of having a global session. You should be doing

```
Session = scoped_session(session_factory, scopefunc=flask._app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__)
return Session
```

instead of

```
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
return Session()
```

And do

```
session = Session()
```

every time you need a session. By virtue of the `scoped_session` and the `scopefunc`, this will return you a different session in each request, but the same session in the same request.

Comment: I did what you said, and I put self.session = db.Session() in the __init__ function for a new APIResource(Resource) class, but I'm having the same problem...  I add something to the database and delete it in separate threads, but the adding thread remembers the thing.

Comment: @Scott You're saying you have multiple threads *within the same request*?

Comment: No.  Just the gunicorn threads.  I think the problem with this solution is that I need to tear down the session at the end of the request somewhere.

Comment: @Scott Well, yes. You weren't doing that before? Again, I highly recommend using flask-sqlalchemy, as it takes care of that for you.

Comment: @univerio I'm having trouble understanding what the effective difference between `scoped_session(session_factory)` and `scoped_session(session_factory, scopefunc=flask._app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__)` is. In the former, we are using thread local storage - each thread that calls `Session()` will get it's own session. Each request to the Flask will create a new thread and thus get it's own session.  Why isn't this effectively the same as the latter?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen "Each request to the Flask will create a new thread and thus get it's own session." This is not (necessarily) true. WSGI does not define a threading model.

Comment: @univerio If I'm running the Gunicorn `sync` worker_class, is it necessarily true?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I could be wrong, but I don't think so. The `sync` worker is just a single thread, so you just share the same `Session` object between requests if you don't use a proper `scopefunc`.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen, [this section][1] of the SA Docs describe the difference between the two `scoped_session` invocations. The latter is a "custom scope" that is a more appropriate tight-coupling of the _session registry_ created by `scoped_session` to the life-cycle of a request in Flask. Other web frameworks would have their own `scopefunc` that is specific to that framework. The section(s) above discusses why a tight-coupling of your session to request is a good idea.

[1]: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.  What I did was to add a setup and teardown to the request in my app's __init__.py:

```
@app.before_request
def startup_session():
    db.session = db.connectSQLAlchemy()

@app.teardown_request
def shutdown_session(exception=None): 
    db.session.close()
```

still using the global session object in my db module:

```
db.py:

....
session = None
....
```

The `scoped_session` handles the different threads, I think...

Please advise if this is a terrible way to do this for some reason.  =c)

Comment: `scoped_session` does not handle multiple threads like this. As soon as you have multiple threads you're going to run into trouble.

Comment: You need to connect in a per-process fashion, eg 4 procs = 4 DB connections and open Sessions in a per-request fashion 1 request = 1 new Session.

Comment: @alextsil "connect in a per-process fashion" so `db.connectSQLAlchemy()` creates both a connection AND a session?

Comment: @Him No, you need to run the `create_engine` inside an `@app.before.server_start` listener and then `create new session` inside an `@app.before_request` listener. (The naming is not precise but you get the idea.) This way each worker will get its own connection pool and each request will get its own session.