# SQLAlchemy: session.begin_nested() with session.commit()

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, transactions, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, with `autocommit` set to `False` and `autoflush` set to `True`. It's connecting to a `mysql` database.

I have 3 methods like this:

```
def insert_something():
   insert_statement = <something>
   db.session.execute(insert_statement);
   db.session.commit()

def delete_something():
   delete_statement = <something>
   db.session.execute(delete_statement);
   db.session.commit()

def delete_something_else():
   delete_statement = <something>
   db.session.execute(delete_statement);
   db.session.commit()
```

Sometimes I want to run these methods individually; no problems there — but sometimes I want to run them together in a nested transaction. I want `insert_something` to run first, and `delete_something` to run afterwards, and `delete_something_else` to run last. If any of those methods fail then I want everything to be rolled back.

I've tried the following:

```
db.session.begin_nested()
insert_something()
delete_something()
delete_something_else()
db.session.commit()
```

This doesn't work, though, because `insert_something` exits the nested transaction (and releases the `savepoint`). Then, when `delete_something` runs `db.session.commit()` it actually commits the deletion to the database because it is in the outermost transaction.
That final `db.session.commit()` in the code block above doesn't do anything..everything is already committed by that point.

Maybe I can do something like this, but it's ugly as hell:

```
db.session.begin_nested()
db.session.begin_nested()
db.session.begin_nested()
db.session.begin_nested()
insert_something()
delete_something()
delete_something_else()
db.session.commit()
```

There's gotta be a better way to do it without touching the three methods..

Edit:
Now I'm doing it like this:

```
with db.session.begin_nested():
    insert_something()
with db.session.begin_nested():
    delete_something()
with db.session.begin_nested():
    delete_something_else()

db.session.commit()
```

Which is better, but still not great.

I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
with db.session.begin_nested() as nested:
    insert_something()
    delete_something()
    delete_something_else()
    nested.commit() #  though I feel like you shouldn't need this in a with block
```

Answer (score 3):

The docs discuss avoiding this pattern in [arbitrary-transaction-nesting-as-an-antipattern](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#arbitrary-transaction-nesting-as-an-antipattern) and [session-faq-whentocreate](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#session-faq-whentocreate).

But there is an example in the docs that is similar to this but it is for testing.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html?highlight=after_transaction_end#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites

Regardless, here is a gross transaction manager based on the example that "seems" to work but **don't do this**.  I think there are a lot of gotchas in here.

```py
import contextlib

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    MetaData,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.sql import delete, select

db_uri = 'postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/database'

engine = create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "devices"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))


def get_devices(session):
    return [d.name for (d,) in session.execute(select(Device)).all()]


def create_device(session, name):
    session.add(Device(name=name))
    session.commit()


def delete_device(session, name):
    session.execute(delete(Device).filter(Device.name == name))
    session.commit()


def almost_create_device(session, name):
    session.add(Device(name=name))
    session.flush()
    session.rollback()


@contextlib.contextmanager
def force_nested_transaction_forever(session, commit_on_complete=True):
    """
    Keep re-entering a nested transaction everytime a transaction ends.
    """
    d = {
        'nested': session.begin_nested()
    }
    @event.listens_for(session, "after_transaction_end")
    def end_savepoint(session, transaction):
        # Start another nested trans if the prior one is no longer active.
        if not d['nested'].is_active:
            d['nested'] = session.begin_nested()

    try:
        yield
    finally:
        # Stop trapping us in perpetual nested transactions.
        # Is this the right place for this ?
        event.remove(session, "after_transaction_end", end_savepoint)

    # This seems like it would be error prone.
    if commit_on_complete and d['nested'].is_active:
        d.pop('nested').commit()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    metadata.create_all(engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:
        with session.begin():
            # THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED
            with force_nested_transaction_forever(session):
                create_device(session, "0")
                create_device(session, "a")
                delete_device(session, "a")
                almost_create_device(session, "a")
                create_device(session, "b")
            assert len(get_devices(session)) == 2
        assert len(get_devices(session)) == 2
```

Comment: Hi Ian - so which method would you recommend for nested transactions?

Comment: @Shivani This answer is already getting old with 2.0 but probably explicitly using `SAVEPOINT` if you need true nested transactions otherwise don't put `commit` in your database methods and just wrap your entire "transaction" in a single transaction.